# Analysis Services in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server-2016

I have heard SQL Server 2016 has updated some new features of its Analysis services in past September. can anybody explain me what is new in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything new in AS in the latest CTP 2.4 release. The 2.4 what's new page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb500435.aspx) has a section for AS (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb522628.aspx) but it only has entries up to 2.3 so you can see what was in that release.

That's not uncommon though. Not all components have new capabilities lit up with each new CTP drop.